# Diamond norm distances between some channel and the identity

Tags: quantum-operation, resource-request, depolarizing-channel, diamond-norm

I'm currently working with the continuity result by [Kretschmann-Schlingemann-Werner](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2008.917696) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0605009)) for Stinespring isometries (more precisely, the following corollary to their result, cf. Appendix C in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.03667)):

> Given channels $\Phi_1,\Phi_2\in\mathcal L(\mathbb C^{d\times d})$ with respective Kraus rank $r_1,r_2$, as well as any $m\in\mathbb N$ with $m\geq2\max\{r_1,r_2\}$, for all Stinespring isometries $V_1,V_2:\mathbb C^d\to\mathbb C^d\otimes\mathbb C^m$ of $\Phi_1,\Phi_2$ there exists $U \in\mathsf U(m)$ such
> that
> $$
> \|V_1-({\bf 1}\otimes U)V_2\|_\infty\leq \sqrt{\|\Phi_1-\Phi_2\|_\diamond}\,.
> $$

I was interested in how good this bound is in general, which is why I got interested in finding examples of channels where $\|\Phi_1-\Phi_2\|_\diamond$ is known. However, the only literature I know of in this direction are:

- [the paper of Johnston et al.](https://doi.org/10.26421/QIC9.1-2-2) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3636)) on the (diamond norm-)distance between unitary channels.
- [the paper of Nechita et al.](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5019322) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00401)) on the distance between random channels.
  Therein they give an upper bound on the diamond norm in terms of the
  partial trace of the absolute value of the Choi-Jamiołkowski matrix, and they even characterize when this bound is saturated.
  Moreover, they study the distance between random channels and the maximally depolarizing channel $X\mapsto{\rm tr}(X)d^{-1}{\bf 1}_d$—as well as distances involving random unitary channels—in the asymptotic limit $d\to\infty$.
- more general results on *bounding* the diamond norm, e.g., the inequality $\|\Phi-{\rm id}\|_\diamond\leq 2\sqrt{\|\Phi-{\rm id}\|_{1\to 1}}$ between diamond norm and the operator norm induced by the trace norm from [Watrous's book](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/).

From these, the only analytic result on channel distances seems to be Theorem 12 in the Johnston paper which states that $\|{\rm id}-U(\cdot)U^*\|_\diamond$ is equal to "the diameter of the smallest closed disc that contains all of the eigenvalues of $U$".

Beyond that I proved the following distance results myself (but I am not yet aware of any paper or book that features them):

> Let $\Phi_d$ denote the dephasing channel (i.e. $\Phi_d$ sets all off-diagonal elements of the input to zero)
> and let $\Phi_{\bf 1}:X\mapsto{\rm tr}(X)d^{-1}{\bf 1}$ denote the depolarization channel in dimension $d$. Then
> $$\|{\rm id}-\Phi_{\bf 1}\|_{1\to 1}=\|{\rm id}-\Phi_d\|_{1\to 1}=\|{\rm id}-\Phi_d\|_\diamond=2-\frac2d\leq2-\frac2{d^2}=\|{\rm id}-\Phi_{\bf 1}\|_\diamond \,.$$

Now my question is twofold:

> 1. Are these distance results regarding dephasing and depolarization known, and if so, in what paper/book can I find them?
> 2. Beyond what I listed above, are there any resources which contain distance results of this type (i.e. analytic expressions for $\|{\rm id}-\Phi\|_\diamond$ for specific channels $\Phi$)? For example, a generalization of the depolarization-result would be to consider arbitrary reset channels $\Phi_\rho:X\mapsto {\rm tr}(X)\rho$ (with $\rho$ some state). While numerics suggest a closed-form expression of $\|{\rm id}-\Phi_\rho\|_\diamond$, my proof of the depolarization result breaks down when replacing ${\bf 1}/d$ by an arbitrary state.

Comment: In the meantime, the reason why I asked this question turned into [a paper](https://doi.org/10.26421/QIC23.15-16-5) where I try to extend upon the Kretschmann-Schlingemann-Werner bound. The gist of it is that one can *probably* get rid of the dimension limitation of the dimension of the Stinespring isometry *if* one adds an addition factor of $\sqrt2$ to the upper bound. However, I was only able to prove it for certain special cases; the general case remains a conjecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some useful results in these links: https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2021-08-09-522/, https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4110v1, https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/ab8e5c, https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.08227, and in other papers discussing coherent noise.

Comment: Much appreciated! The paper of Regula et al. has some handy characterizations of the diamond norm (in particular Thm. 3 for Herm.-pres., trace-annihilating maps); however, I have to play around with it some more to see how useful this is for actually computing channel distances